# Spark integration with spring boot web starter

Tags: spring-boot, scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to integrate Spark application with spring boot but since spark core also has jetty server and servlet packages, they are conflicting with spring boot web starter servlet packages.

I already followed the post below to exclude starter-logging

> https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/integrating-spark-spring-boot-neeraj-malhotra

I tried excluding servlet from spark core package, but it wouldn't start up or build using gradle build.

My goal is to run this app as a Rest API using spring boot web starter.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why you need Spark with spring boot?

Comment: I've written a blog out of the blue which demonstrates the integration of Apache Spark + Spring Boot (http://www.technocratsid.com/spring-boot-apache-spark/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found the solution a long time ago, but couldnt post this. I had to exclude a bunch of packages from spark-core that contain servlet packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution a long time ago, but couldn't post this. 
I had to exclude a bunch of packages from spark-core that contain servlet packages

```
 compile(group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '1.6.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
    exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', module: 'jetty-server'
    exclude group: 'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jersey-server'
    exclude group: 'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jetty-core'
    exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.orbit', module: 'javax.servlet'
    //exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', module: 'jetty-server'
}
```